# I want to serve a big file with gin-golang, and want to show the "download" progress bar in Chrome

Tags: go, download, go-gin

I have the following endpoint:

`http://localhost:8080/report/latest`

and it downloads a big file. The thing is that right now, if I use chrome, I just see a spinner and after a few seconds, the file is downloaded. How can I make that there is a progress bar that sometimes you can see when downloading a file?

This is the code that I wrote:

```
func (rc *ReportController) writeOutput(c *gin.Context, b []byte, year int, month time.Month) {
    name := fmt.Sprintf("report-%d-%d.csv", year, month)
    c.Header("Content-Description", "File Transfer")
    c.Header("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "binary")
    c.Header("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(len(b)))
    c.Header("Content-Disposition", fmt.Sprintf("attachment; filename=%s", name))
    c.Header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Disposition")
    c.Data(http.StatusOK, "application/octet-stream", b)
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a frontend task. I would use js XMLHttpRequest (or fetch API if you prefer) to init downloading the file, query 'content-length' header to get the file size and write a hook for the onrogress event to display whatever progress visuals you want display. see https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onprogress.asp

Comment: You cannot enforce this from the server side. (And nobody likes shity JS download bars)